# Swipe touch scroll up and down issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scroll, touch, swipe

I developed a wordpress website and purchased a panoramic jQuery plugin in order to display panoramic galleries

https://codecanyon.net/item/360-panoramic-viewer-jquery-plugin/2684810?s_rank=5

The plugin works and I display panoramic pictures
The only issue I have is that the swipe right and left in mobile prevent from scrolling the page regular scroll up and down when over the images
as you can see here:

http://www.appchee.net/contini/panoramic-gallery/venice-gallery/

(* You have to try it on mobile of course)
I can't find a solution of having the swipe right and left but also enabling the scroll up and down regardless where I am on the page including over the images

Anyone has a clue
Even a twick will help

Thanks